# How to sync commands globally with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to sync all of my slash commands with my discord bot but when I run my sync command for some reason it is not working.

My client variable is created as the following

```
client = commands.Bot(intents=INTENTS, command_prefix=PREFIX)
```

The command I have to sync my slash commands is

```
@client.command()
async def sync(ctx):
    print("sync command")
    if ctx.author.id == my_id:
        await client.tree.sync()
        await ctx.send('Command tree synced.')
    else:
        await ctx.send('You must be the owner to use this command!')
```

When running this command I do get the sent message meaning that the `tree.sync()` function went through however it doesn't seem to be doing anything, is there a certain amount of time it takes for the commands to sync or is this written incorrectly?

Also
`await client.tree.sync(guild=None)`
Does not work either.

Comment: Syncing commands globally can take up to one, or even two hours.

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I left the script running overnight and the commands never appeared in other servers so I believe there is a problem with the script.

Comment: Keep in mind that for your command to work on all servers, you need to define it as a global command, ie not specify a guild to the `@app_commands.command()`/`@client.tree.command()` decorators.